# MS Word 365 Equation Numbering Formatting with Chapter Number

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016, equations

I am writing a document in there are equations, each of which should have the chapter number and the equation number (e.g., 2.1). I would prefer my equations remain in display mode, so I am using the trick outlined [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/equation-numbering-in-office-2016) to handle the formatting. The problem comes when I try to use fields for auto numbering. The formatting places space immediately after the punctuation when I use any fields, but not when I manually type the number (see below). This space is a formatting feature rather than a character, so I cannot delete it.

[image: Equation numbering with and without fields]

Is there a way to fix the formatting so that using fields for my equation numbering does not insert extra space in the number?